# Is there a package for the correction of a homework?

Tags: exam, answers

I have a maths homework to do and I got the LaTeX source code of the subject. I would like to naturally insert the answers in the same document, in order to submit a homogeneous work, but don't know any non-artisanal solution. I know the package "exam" and its "answer" option exist, but I've got the impression that it is only for short answers. Do you know any solution or relevant template ?

Comment: Welcome! If you have the source, just stick to the class etc. the homework uses. You don't want to mess around redoing the questions with some other class or package and there really isn't any point. The packages you mention are useful for people writing exams and homework assignments, but you aren't doing that and don't need fancy ways to e.g. suppress your answers or include them depending on your target audience. Just put your answers inline in whatever you've got.

Comment: The downvote seems a bit harsh here ... perhaps the perpetrator could explain their thinking? I agree with @cfr --- just do something simple like `\section*{Solution}` after each question and then insert your answer.